# Ошибка сегментирования (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, классы, указатели

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char slot_desc[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

typedef struct SlotInfo
{
    char slotDescription[10];   

}SLOT;

struct GeneralSlot
{
    SLOT *SlotInf;
};

GeneralSlot *Slot1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Slot1->SlotInf = NULL;
    memmove(Slot1->SlotInf->slotDescription, slot_desc, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

В данном коде получаю Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти). Компилирую под Linux. Что я делаю не так или чего-то не понимаю с указателями?
При запуске от имени суперпользователя ошибку не выдает, но все равно копирование не выполняется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Comment: Вы задаете `Slot1->SlotInf=NULL` и тут же пытаетесь обратится к полую по этому указателью, т.е. по факту делаете `NULL->slotDescription`

Comment: @Mike, ответы в ответы?

Comment: Хотя ошибка еще раньше происходит. Вы определяете указатель Slot1 но он изначально никуда не смотрит. Надо выделить память для хранения структуры GeneralSlot и присвоить адрес этой области памяти этому указателю

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, разобрался!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы совершаете одну и ту же ошибку дважды.

В этом предложении объявлен указатель в глобальном пространстве имен

```
GeneralSlot *Slot1;
```

Компилятор инициализирует этот указатель нулем. Фактически это объявление эквивалентно объявлению

```
GeneralSlot *Slot1 = NULL;
```

То есть данный указатель не указывает ни на какой реальный объект типа  `GeneralSlot`. Поэтому попытка разыменовать такой указатель в предложении

```
Slot1->SlotInf = NULL;
```

ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Даже если бы указатель `Slot1` указывал бы на реальный объект, тем не менее вы повторяете предыдущую ошибку, инициализировав уже другой указатель `Slot1->SlotInf` этого объекта нулем, и пытаясь что-то записать в память по нулевому адресу

```
memmove(Slot1->SlotInf->slotDescription, slot_desc, 5);
```

Вам надо, чтобы оба указателя указывали на реальные объекты. Вы могли бы написать, к примеру,

```
// ...

GeneralSlot *Slot1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Slot1 = new GeneralSlot;

    Slot1->SlotInf = new SLOT;

    memmove(Slot1->SlotInf->slotDescription, slot_desc, 5);

    // ...

    delete Slot1->SlotInf;
    delete Slot1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за подробное объяснение. С указателями мало знаком, поэтому и туплю на ровном месте)

Comment: Если я правильно помню, компилятор не обязан инициализировать глобальные переменные нулём, если они не объявлены как статические.

Comment: @0andriy Все глобальные переменные имеют статическую память,, которая инициализируется нулем. Переменные, объявленные с ключевым словом static, имеют внутреннее связывание. Тем не менее, они имеют статическую память.

Answer (score 3):

Итак, глобальная переменная

```
GeneralSlot *Slot1;
```

т.е. инициализированная нулем. После чего

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Slot1->SlotInf = NULL;
```

И куда вы записываете этот `NULL`? В `NULL`?
Вот и получаете то, что получаете...

Выделите память для `GeneralSlot`, на которую будет указывать `Slot1`.